# How to do following in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sequence, matlab-figure

Suppose I have a sequence of `n` numbers

```
e=[5,4,45,63,22,22,1,12,3,2,2,16,14,14,16,17,1,19,21,15,32,32,27,27,43,41,7,8,13,23,23]
```

then for first `10` numbers i.e.

```
[5,4,45,63,22,22,1,12,3,2]
```

count numbers other than `1` to `5` and then divide by `10`, i.e.

```
[45,63,22,22,12]
```

total `5`, so result should be `5/10`,now for first `20` numbers i.e.

```
[5,4,45,63,22,22,1,12,3,2,2,16,14,14,16,17,1,19,21,15]
```

then

```
[45,63,22,22,12,16,14,14,16,17,19,21,15]
```

total = `13`, so `13/20`, like this for `10`, `20`, `30`,... up to `n` numbers
and then plot figure with `x` axis points `0` `10` `20` `30` ... `n` and `y` axis with `5/10`, `13/20`, ... how to do this

I tried by this

```
for e=10:10:400
    for u=1:length(e)
        d=(numel(u)>5)
        h=d/u
    end
end
```

but it shows different.

Comment: Use a `for`-loop, the `:` operator and basic logical indexing i.e. `totals(k) = sum(e(1:k) > 10)`. Try it yourself and edit your question to show you've attempted it yourself before asking for code

Comment: please show what you have tried.

Comment: Hi! Is there a reason why you want to implement this particular algorithm? Is it a homework assignment of sorts?

Comment: It requires for project

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
e= [5,4,45,63,22,22,1,12,3,2,2,16,14,14,16,17,1,19,21,15,32,32,27,27,43,41,7,8,13,23,23];

bins = 10:10:numel(e);
counts = NaN(1,numel(bins));  %// pre-allocation. I'm pre-allocating with NaN here instead of zeros because 0 is a valid result for an element of counts and thus could make us miss errors should something go wrong
for k = 1:numel(bins)
    counts(k) = sum(e(1:bins(k)) > 5)/bins(k);
end

plot(bins, counts)  %// or you might prefer bar(bins, counts)
```

Here `e(1:bins(k))` will be the first `10` elements of `e` in the first iteration of the loop, the first `20` in the second and so on. `sum(... > 10)` just counts how many elements are greater than `5`. To understand how this works, consider `x = [3 4 5 6 7 8 5 1 2]`. Now `x > 5` will return the logical array `[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]`, so `sum(x>10)` is the same as `sum([0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0])` which is `3` i.e. the count of elements in `x` greater than `5`. Now you just need to store this count in a different element of `counts` at each iteration hence we have `counts(k) = ...` and not `counts = ...` as the latter (i.e. how your code has it) just overrides `counts` with the scalar count at each iteration rather than creating a vector that records each count at each iteration.

In MATLAB you can often do away with loops and you can do so in this case as well:

```
counts = cumsum(e > 5)./(1:numel(e));
h = counts(10:10:end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this can help you

```
n=30               % this because of the 'e' size
Lim = 5            % your limit
Steps = 10         % 

xValues = Steps:Steps:n
PlotSeries = NaN(size(e,2)/Steps,2)

for x = 1:1:size(e,2)/Steps
    PlotSeries(x,:) = [xValues(x),size(e(e(1:xValues(x))>Lim),2)/xValues(x)]
end

plot(PlotSeries)
```